# Program using Atomic Variable gets stuck unexpectedly

Tags: c++, asynchronous, concurrency, stdatomic

I have a program utilizing a thread pool and atomic variables for synchronization within an event-driven architecture. However, it appears to get stuck unexpectedly under certain conditions, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause.

I want to realize a fence event acts as a synchronization point, blocking the event loop until all preceding events have completed their execution. This is achieved through the use of an atomic variable `ntasks`.

The `ntasks` variable serves to count the number of ongoing event tasks. It is incremented when an event begins execution (`begin_event()`) and decremented when an event completes (`end_event()`). If the count reaches zero, it signals the event loop to proceed.

Here's a simplified version of my code.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdio>
#include "ThreadPool.h"

enum event_t {
    update, render, fence = 0xffffffff
};

std::mutex queue_mutex;
std::queue<event_t> queue;
std::atomic<long long> ntasks;
ThreadPool thread_pool(4);

std::mutex loop_mutex;
std::condition_variable loop_cv;

void publish_event(event_t t) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    queue.push(t);
}

bool try_get_event(event_t& x) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    if (queue.empty())
        return false;
    x = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    return true;
}

void onUpdate() {
    printf("%s", "Update!");
    publish_event(render);
    publish_event(fence); // Wait until render event finished
    publish_event(update); // Start the next pass
}

void onRender() {
    // Pass
}

// Called before event execution start
void begin_event()
{
    ntasks.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release); // Increase the count of excution tasks
}

void end_event()
{
    if (ntasks.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == 1) // Decrease the count of excution tasks
        loop_cv.notify_one(); // If there are no more tasks, we can notify to release the fence
}


int main() {
    publish_event(update); // Initial event to start the event loop

    // Event Loop
    while (true) {
        event_t event;
        if (try_get_event(event)) {

            switch (event) {
            case update:
                begin_event();
                thread_pool.enqueue([] { onUpdate(); end_event(); });
                break;
            case render:
                begin_event();
                thread_pool.enqueue([] { onRender(); end_event(); });
                break;
            case fence:
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(loop_mutex);
                // Wait until there are no more tasks
                loop_cv.wait(lock, [] { return ntasks.load(std::memory_order_acquire) <= 0; });
            }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The weirdest, if I use debugger or add some output statements, the issue is not reproducible.

It seems to be getting stuck at the `loopCv.wait()` point. This is because when I replace it with a spin lock, the issue disappears.

```
case fence:
    while (ntasks.load(std::memory_order_acquire) > 0);
```

The thread pool used is from: https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool

The platform I used is MSVC compiler, Windows system and Intel i7-10750H CPU.

Despite these mechanisms in place, the program encounters unexpected blocking issues, possibly due to synchronization or deadlock problems.

Could someone review my code and provide insights into why it might get stuck unexpectedly? Additionally, any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: Would be better to add `ThreadPool.h` to the question instead of using the link. Does the author of this thread pool guarantee thread-safety of `enqueue` operations? Because you are often calling `thread_pool.enqueue` from the worker threads.

Comment: @pptaszni it does look like it's threadsafe

Comment: Where does it get stuck? Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Also, what is your stop condition? It seems that when your queue is empty, you are left with infinite loop without any side effects.

Comment: My take is that atomics are lousy synchronization  points for anything other than the atomic itself.

Comment: The thread safety of the thread pool does not matter. It only called on the main thread. It  
 may be confusing that I made the function to publish the event called "enqueue" too.

Comment: This is weird; the issue is not reproducible when I use the debugger. Even if I output something before waiting for the condition variable, it prevents the problem from occurring.

Comment: If you concede to the control variable hypothesis, it seems to be getting stuck at the `loopCv.wait()` point. This is evident because when I replace it with a spin lock, the issue disappears.

Comment: I try to use a common variable and `std::mutex` as a substitute for atomic variable `nTasks`, but it does not work.

Comment: I haven't thought this all the way through, but I see a big red flag. `loop_mutex` is only ever being used in one thread. That means it has zero benefit. You might as well not lock it at all. But of course, you are using it because `loop_cv.wait(...)` _requires_ you to use it. I _suspect_ that the problem here is a _lost notification,_ and I suspect that the reason it's happening is because you aren't using the mutex that `wait` requires in the way that you're supposed to use it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow actually, I'm pretty sure that's not the case. "notify_one" and "notify_all" do not need the mutex, so it should be completely fine -- you are allowed to just signal the variable whenever you want to.

In fact, the way he uses it, I think I've done that somewhere as well -- even without the global mutex because it didn't have to be global, so I just used a mutex as a local variable...

Comment: I'm somewhat concerned about the memory order stuff, but I don't need that kind of micro-optimization which means I've never used that, so I don't know whether the values you chose are correct. I would probably just use the queue_mutex for everything, ditch the atomic and the loop mutex, and avoid all headaches.

Did you try just leaving out those values? They default to something rather strict

Comment: @ChristianStieber, So, why does `wait` require a reference to a mutex? Why does wait unlock the mutex and then re-lock it again before returning? Why can't it simply _wait_ and if the programmer who uses it thinks they need a mutex, why not let the calling code unlock the mutex before calling wait() and re-lock the mutex after wait() returns?

Comment: @ChristianStieber, Here's what I think can happen: 1. Main thread enters `fence` case, enters `wait` call, tests `ntasks`, and finds it to be greater than zero. 2. worker thread calls `end_event`, decrements `ntasks`, notifies `loop_cv`. 3. Main thread, still inside `wait` call, actually starts to wait for the notification. But it's too late. The notification already happened. Even if another worker calls `end_event`, there will never be another notification, because the workers only call notify when `ntasks` is exactly equal to `1`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have never implemented a condition variable myself, so I don't know whether the mutex is a requirement or a tradition. However, condition variables are not usually used around atomic values -- more often than not, they are used to deal with things like queues which require the mutex anyway, and having the "re-acquire the mutex before checking/returning" semantics is extremely helpful in such cases...

Comment: @ChristianStieber, I've used lots of them. The mutex absolutely _is_ a requirement. The reason `wait` requires a reference to a mutex is because the mutex is supposed to stop other threads from changing the condition in-between the time when `wait` tests it, and the time when `wait` actually begins waiting for the notification.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm kind of beginning to see a possible problem, which DOES in fact include your observation that the mutex isn't used when modifying the variable. While notify() can and should be called outside of the mutex, the mutex still guarantees that the variable doesn't change when the condition variable wants to call the predicate function... so yes, that mutex is likely needed to protect the data, even if the data doesn't need protection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to get the lock of `loop_mutex` before notify the event loop.